# Cast JSON array as type for Typescript class property

Tags: json, typescript, class

I have made a TypeScript class like this:

```
export class MyClassName {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    data: /* JSON ARRAY */;
}
```

What I want to do is to cast the "data" property as a JSON array ( [JSON, JSON, JSON].... ).

I've tried the following:

```
export class MyClassName {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    data: [key: any];
}
```

When serving the app using "ng serve" it gives this error message but the app still functions as intended:

> ERROR in src/app/myclass.ts(4,14): error TS1005: ',' expected.

but when I'm trying to build it using "ng build --prod" it fails to build due to the same error message.

Comment: since it's an array of anything, how about `any[]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If its an array of stringified `JSON`, you can just use `string[]`. Else, you can
>   use the following.

```
export class MyClassName {
    id   : number;
    name : string;
    data : {[key: string]: any}[];
}
```

Comment: You should really test your code before you post: `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Edited, My bad.